# Purely following Redux way and having Dump | Presentational components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When you create React components, do you mostly follow the philosophy of only having dump/presentational react components that are connected to Containers? Only having dump components fulfils one of the main principles of redux (single source of truth) but complicated things when it comes to component isolation. By that i mean that:

... i end up have a table component which can present data and have the ability to select rows, but selection don't work unless its connected to the store via a container. This is good in *theory* because a lot of other components rely on that selection so having everything going through the store keeps *everything in sync*. However, it means that the table component cannot be fully interactable by itself (selection won't work if its not connected to the store). This could make automated UI tests slightly harder to test as each component will need to have a related container in order to work properly.

Another example; say that you have a dialog box, would you have the show state within the component itself or have it connected to the store through a container?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the **Presentational and Container Components** approach. It make the code clearer, cleaner and way more reusable.

The idea behind it is that your Presentational Component **MUST NOT** perform any action on the data, it is purely UI. And this data must come from your container (from the Redux Store, or from an helper class etc.)

The best practice is to pass down your Presentational Components functions from your Container Components via props.

```
// Container Component

handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({ username : e })
}

render() {
  return (
    <Boarding
      placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
      error={this.state.error} 
      onChangeText={this.handleChange}
      name={this.props.FB_user.user_firstname}
      ProfilPicture={this.props.FB_user.user_picture} />
  )
}

export default connect((state) => ({
  FB_user: state.statusLogin,
}), {})(BoardingContainer)
```

Here is a simple example on how you can pass a function down your Presentational Component (which is TextInput here) and get connect to it to get back the data inputed in the TextInput.

Also, if you watch closely you'll see I pass `this.props.FB_user.user_firstname` && `this.props.FB_user.user_picture` that comes from the Redux Store that I connected to using the last lines of the code example.

Here is a very famous Medium article to get more details : https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.smfbi5hjj

Hope this helps, if you have any more questions, ask me.